Jenkins SQLRunnerBuilder : Capture error messages
I have three scripts that create table1, table2, and table3. I need to deploy these in different environments, and for this purpose, I am creating a Jenkins pipeline to execute my SQL scripts.
During the first run, all scripts are executed successfully and the tables are created. However, in subsequent runs, Oracle is giving an error message: "object already exists," which is displayed in the deployment log file.
How can we capture this validation/error message so that we can update the build status based on it?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sqlplus-script-runner/


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Run SQL Scripts') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def scripts = ['script1.sql', 'script2.sql', 'script3.sql']
                        for (script in scripts) {
                            step([$class: 'SQLPlusRunnerBuilder', 
                                      credentialsId: 'your-credentials-id', 
                                      instance: 'your-instance', 
                                      scriptType: 'file', 
                                      script: script])
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




What's SQLRunnerBuilder?

And does Jenkins have access to that "deployment log file"?

It is a plugin available. Please check here  https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sqlplus-script-runner/

It’s SQLPlusRunnerBuilder. Did you use copy paste?

Messing around with Jenkin's build status and internals is a pain.
If I were doing this I'd change the SQL script that creates the tables to check for their existence before running things:
IF((SELECT count(*) FROM dba_tables where table_name = 'TABLE_1') <= 0)
THEN
create table TABLE_1
(
ID NUMBER(3),
NAME VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
)
END IF;

This will only handle your issue you have now which is running the script after the table has been created causes a failure.  The next issue you'll have is how to make updates to the existing tables as you change the schema.  But, that is fairly complex problem to deal with.  You may want to adopt tools like liquidbase or some schema management framework.

How can we capture the result of the step execution and catch ORA errors?

That's probably going to have to be something in SQLPlusRunnerBuilder.  Otherwise you'd need to use PL/SQL to trap errors, but that would just be in the SQL script which is why the SQLPlusRunnerBuilder would need to trap it as an exception and communicate that to Jenkins.  You may need to ask a new question on SO with details on what you are expecting to do when errors occur.

If you go to this page https://plugins.jenkins.io/sqlplus-script-runner/ there is a lot more information about the plugin, and from there you can get to the git page to ask the developer these details.  That might be the fastest option.
